# Ubuntu ./filename command not found

Tags: ubuntu

I am on Ubuntu 16 and when I try to run the following command
`sudo ./filename` I get an error saying `sudo: ./filename: command not found` When i can see that there is a file of that name in the directory im in.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. In my scripts directory, I ran `sudo ./some_script.sh` and it worked. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I don't know how I would be able to provide a minimal reproducible example. I can provide a link to an image showing the issue If you want. I aslo just tried this in my centos 6 vps and it gives me the same error

Comment: Maybe try running `./filename` without `sudo`?

Comment: Then it gives me an error saying I dont have permission to do that.

Comment: [link to picture](https://postimg.cc/MckTbx7R)

Comment: Post the output of `ls -l update`

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 856452 Nov  7 22:55 update`

Comment: This question should have been asked at [ubuntu.se] instead, as it's an operating system question and not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our conversation in the comments, the file doesn't have [execute permission](https://superuser.com/q/117704/443564). You need to add execute permission first:

```
sudo chmod u+x filename
```

(Using `u` here makes it just for the owner, i.e. `root`.)

Or if it's a script, you can run its interpreter instead. For example, Bash:

```
sudo bash filename
```